# Git hub : Issue pushing changes to remote server through Xamarin Studio

Tags: git, github, git-branch, xamarin-studio, branching-and-merging

I'm using git hub for version control with my Xamarin studio project and I've created two branches:one master(default) and one local for committing my work.

But I'm facing an issue while committing to my remote master branch through my local branch. Currently I'm working on my local branch and whenever I make some changes, I can successfully commit them and push changes on the local.But when I try to push those changes on the remote master branch it gives me this error :

**Cannot push non-fastforwardable reference**

I cannot understand what is the issue or how should I push the changes made on my local branch onto my remote master branch through Xamarin studio.

Has anyone faced this issue and resolved it or knows what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I'm using Xamarin studio and not the command line for updating my code on the server.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local branch and the branch on the remote server diverged. You need to pull the changes from the remote server and merge them with your local branch. Afterwards you can push your branch to the server.

Comment: I did it once. But do I need to pull a request from my server every time I'm making changes in my local branch?  I mean is it the only way to push my changes to the server? Can't I just push the changes made, directly from my local branch in Xamarin studio to the remote branch?

Comment: Also it will be very helpful if you guide me on how to work with multiple branches of a project as I am totally new to git hub.